# Как стилизовать .swiper-pagination в swiper?

Tags: javascript, css, swiper

У меня в js файле прописан следующий код:

```
pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'fraction',
        formatFractionCurrent: function (number) {
            return '0' + number;
        },
    },
```

Я стилизовал сами номера слайдов, как мне надо. Но есть слеш, который непонятно как стилизовать. Я бы хотел изменить у него размер и цвет. Как это сделать?